# JavaScript and Data store in database

Tags: javascript, mysql

Here i am providing my code where the data need to store in MySQL database getting from JavaScript file.

Script File code

```
 function set_shield(t_value){
           var ok = confirm("Are you sure want Lock Value?")
                                if (ok)
                                {
                                    xmlhttp.open("GET","p_scripts/dataStore.php?set_value="+shield.value,true);
                                    xmlhttp.send();
                                    window.location.reload(true);
                                    }                           
                        }
```

My dataStore.php code contains as below:

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   $set_value=$_GET[set_value];
   include("php_scripts\db.php"); // connection create here
   $date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   mysql_query("Update user SET p1='y' WHERE  user_id='$_SESSION[login_user]'");
   mysql_query("INSERT power_play (user_id, p_play_type, date_of_play, set_value) VALUES ('$_SESSION[login_user]','1','$date','$set_value')");

    ?>
```

Comment: No data store in data base after execute

Comment: What is your intention exactly with that `window.location.reload(true);` over there?

Comment: need to refresh the page for seeing effective changes

Comment: But ajax calls is asynchronous so it's reloding before your `xmlhttp.send()` function actually finishes performing.

Comment: should i remove the  xmlhttp.send()

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Insert` query is not proper .
 Try this out :

```
   INSERT into power_play (user_id, p_play_type, date_of_play, set_value)
        VALUES ('$_SESSION[login_user]','1','$date','$set_value')");
```

Comment: window.location.reload(true); is this on write position .. it gives full page reload.. any suggestion for making a div reloading

Comment: From where your **set_shield(t_value)** function called ?

Comment: it called from main page where a text box value should be store and a button call the function with on-click.

Comment: So where is you face problem , In javascript OR in Php script ?

Comment: in JavaScript .. at 
 
window.location.reload(true);  need to refresh the page for seeing effective changes

Comment: you can try this property for request window.location.assign("Your url").

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below on the client side

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", p_scripts/dataStore.php?set_value="+shield.value,true);
xhr.send();
```